# nuget web.config.uninstall.xdt transform not working

Tags: nuget

I created a nuget package and using xdt transform which updates the web.config file. The web.config.install.xdt works fine as it puts the entires in the web.config file, but when I uninstall the package, seems like the web.config.uninstall.xdt does not run and does not remove the added entires.
Here's what I've in my web.config.uninstall.xd:-

```
<system.web>
    <roleManager cacheRolesInCookie="true" defaultProvider="ADSMRoleProvider" enabled="true" xdt:Transform="Remove">
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out there were xdt tranform at the bottom of the config file which required cleanup and seems to work now